# cytoscape js wrong click coordinate on mobile web

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, cytoscape.js

I just use the cytoscape.js to draw the tree diagram in my website . In desktop web browser , nothing goes wrong . And I also testing the web on android mobile web , but the problem occurred. when I tab the screen , the cursor not appear on the position where's I tapped but on top left from the tap position . I also test it in iphone web browser , the same problem occurred.

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf0YE.png)

My cytoscape code :

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    layout: {
        name: 'dagre',
        padding: 10,
        roots:'#j'
    },

    zoom:1,
    wheelSensitivity: 0.1,
    spacingFactor: 0.1,
    boxSelectionEnabled: false,

    elements: {
        nodes: [
          { data: { id: 'j', name: 'Test1', weight: 65, faveColor: '#6FB1FC', faveShape: 'triangle' } },
          { data: { id: 'e', name: 'Test2', weight: 45, faveColor: '#EDA1ED', faveShape: 'ellipse' } },
          { data: { id: 'k', name: 'Test3', weight: 75, faveColor: '#86B342', faveShape: 'octagon' } },
        ],
        edges: [
          { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e', faveColor: '#6FB1FC'} },
          { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k', faveColor: '#EDA1ED' } },
        ]
    },

    style:[ 
        {
            selector:'node',
            style:{
                'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
                'width': 'mapData(weight, 40, 80, 10, 40)',
                'height': 'mapData(weight, 40, 80, 10, 30)',
                'content': 'data(name)',
                'text-valign': 'center',
                'text-outline-width': 1,
                'text-outline-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                'color': '#fff',
                'font-size': '7px'
            }
        },
        {
            selector:':selected',
            style:{
                'border-width': 3,
                'border-color': '#f47742'
            }
        },
        {
            selector:'edge',
            style:{
                'curve-style': 'bezier',
                'opacity': 0.666,
                'width': 3,
                'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                'line-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                'source-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                'target-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)',
            }
        },
        {
            selector:'edge.questionable',
            style:{
                'line-style': 'dotted',
                'target-arrow-shape': 'diamond'
            }
        },
        {
            selector:'.faded',
            style:{
                'opacity': 0.25,
                'text-opacity': 0
            }
        }]
});

cy.on('click', 'node', function(evt){
      alert("test");
});

cy.minZoom(1);
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your device name, os version, browser version, etc.  Please also link out to a full example of your code on something like JSBin.

Comment: here is the code https://jsbin.com/qusamirile/3/edit?html,output . I also have found the cause of this error. in css , I have *{zoom:0.97;} . If I delete that line , the problem does not occurred anymore. But I also need that zoom configuration .  I test the web using ASUS ZC550KL (ASUS Browser v2.1.2.47_160428 & Chrome 51.0.2704.81) and iphone 5 (safari browser)

Comment: The zoom property is not standard (yet anyway).  If you want a responsive design, then use media queries to alter standard properties like font size.

Comment: ok ,thanks @maxkfranz